# How to use a variable in a string when chosing from a list randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

So I'm attempting to randomly choose a string from a list and include a variable at any point in the string.

I've already tried enclosing the string and variable in parenthesis and single quotes and those two havent worked.

```py
test = "mark"

markthings = [(test + "went to the store."), (test, "wants to die."), ("At the store, ", test, " was being a idiot.")]

print(random.choice(markthings))
```

I expect it to print something like "At the store, mark was being an idiot."

Instead I get, "('At the store,' ,'mark', ' was being a idiot.')

Comment: string concatenation in Python uses the. '+' symbol. You have it correctly in the first object, but used ',' instead on the other two. Just replace the ',' with '+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally made the last two elements a tuple by using `,` instead of a `+` for a concatenated string like you did in the first element.

```
In [23]: test = "mark" 
    ...: markthings = [(test + "went to the store."), (test, "wants to die."), ("At the store, ", te
    ...: st, " was being a idiot.")]                                                                

In [24]: [type(item) for item in markthings]                                                        
Out[24]: [str, tuple, tuple]
```

Once you change `markthings` accordingly to make each element a string, it will work as intended

```
markthings = [(test + "went to the store."), (test+ "wants to die."), ("At the store, "+ test+ " was being a idiot.")]
```

You can also make the instantation of `markthings` easier by using string formatting, example [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
markthings = [f"{test} went to the store.", f"{test} wants to die.", f"At the store, {test} was being a idiot."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
import random
test = "mark"

markthings = [(test, "went to the store."), (test, "wants to die."), ("At the store, ", test, " was being a idiot.")]

print(" ".join(random.choice(markthings)))
```